# Scrapy not executing all rules for CrawlSpider

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following scraper:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class SpiderOpUpcoming(CrawlSpider):
    
    name = "upcoming"
    start_urls = ["https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/"]
    custom_settings = {"USER_AGENT": "*"}
    
    tournament_linkxtr = LinkExtractor(
        allow="/tennis/",
        restrict_xpaths=(
            "//table[@id='sport_content_tennis' and @class='table-main sportcount']"
            "//a[@foo='f']"
        ),
    )
    match_linkxtr = LinkExtractor(
        allow="/tennis/",
        restrict_xpaths=("//td[@class='name table-participant']//a"),
    )
    
    rules = (
        Rule(tournament_linkxtr, callback="parse_tournament", follow=True),
        Rule(match_linkxtr, callback="parse_match", follow=True),
    )
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301]

    def parse_tournament(self, response):
        print("TOURNAMENT -", response.url)

    def parse_match(self, response):
        print("MATCH -", response.url)


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(SpiderOpUpcoming)
process.start()
```

The `parse_tournament` prints fine but no luck with `parse_match`.

To troubleshoot I changed the `start_urls` to be a URL from a 'tournament' page that is scraped by the scraper above via `tournament_linkxtr`. I then removed the `Rule` with the `callback` to `parse_tournament`. See below:

```
start_urls = ["https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/usa/champaign-challenger-men"]
rules = (Rule(match_linkxtr, callback="parse_match", follow=True))
```

The scraper then prints from `parse_match` so the XPath is ok. I also don't think I have any issues with rule order so I'm stumped.

Could anyone shed any light on where I'm going wrong?

Scrapy version is 2.4.1. OSX Monterey on a 2016 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing:

```
handle_httpstatus_list = [301]
```

To:

```
httperror_allowed_codes = [301]
```

Sorted this for me. See the docs [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html?highlight=handle_httpstatus_list#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror).